# Why Global exception handler always return 200 status?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I made a global exception handler to catch my wraped business exception.
I want to return a different status code and a custom response for each wraped exception.

So i made a global exception handler :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExportWordProfileExceptionControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler({ExportWordProfileException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<ApiError> exportWordProfileException(
            ExportWordProfileException ex) {

        if (ex.getCause() instanceof ProfileNotFoundException) {
            var apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, ex.getCause().getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        var apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

}
```

When i testing my controller which throw ExportWordProfileException, i
always got 200 status code. But i have the correct error message :

```
<200,{"data":{"status":"NOT_FOUND","message":"Le profile avec l'id '8e6d45ca-d08f-48b8-8ed0-ea7ea067cf5e' n'existe pas."}} .....
```

How can i fix this problem ?
thanks for reading.

..............
edit
.............

<s>May this problem come from my way to test with RestTemplate ?</s>
I tested with Postman and i have the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i found what was the problem.

The project has another controller advice (ResponseBodyAdvice) made by a previous person. This controller changes the status code dependings of the response body object. So i return a generic rest error object in my controller designed by the previous person (i had no idea this error existing). This generic error was already taken in consideration by the ResponseBodyAdvice controller.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your code. The probable cause of your issue is because another exception handler is interfering with your ExportWordProfileExceptionControllerAdvice.

Comment: Yes it was that see my previous response.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. I think you need to add the @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN) annotation to tell what status to send back for the exception:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {

    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalControllerExceptionHandler.class);

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)  // 403
    @ExceptionHandler(ForbiddenException.class)
    public void handleForbidden() {
        LOG.info("Forbidden handler invoked");
    }

}
```

Comment: i can't use @responseStatus because i return different status depending on the wrapped exception

Comment: What I would do in your situation is have different handler methods for each general response you want to send back (i.e. 200, 401, 403, 404.....) and catch the wrapped exception where it's caused and re-throw it as the http response-specific exception,,,,,I realize that is easier to write then do....I find spring works better with many small methods that do 1 thing